# D3 Matrix table

Tags: javascript, matrix, d3.js

I am able to develop this matrix but I think code can be improved. I am creating a map on which each rectangle may have zero through many list items with their titles (still need to add code for adding titles):

```js
var width = 600,
height = 600;
var margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5};

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 15])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", width)
                                    .attr("height", height)
                                    .style("background-color", "black")
                                    .append("g")
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
                                    .call(zoom);

var zoomed = function () {
    svgContainer.attr("transform", "translate("+ d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
};

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 8])
.on("zoom", zoomed)
.size([width, height]);

svgContainer.call(zoom);

var rectangle1 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 0)
                            .attr("y", 0)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");


var rectangle2 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 100)
                            .attr("y", 0)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "yellow");

var rectangle3 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 200)
                            .attr("y", 0)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");

var rectangle4 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 0)
                            .attr("y", 100)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "yellow");


var rectangle5 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 100)
                            .attr("y", 100)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");

var rectangle6 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 200)
                            .attr("y", 100)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "yellow");


var rectangle7 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 0)
                            .attr("y", 200)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");


var rectangle8 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 100)
                            .attr("y", 200)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "yellow");

var rectangle9 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 200)
                            .attr("y", 200)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this?

```
var rects = [ 
    [0, 0, "#C0FC3E"],
    [0, 200, "#60FC60"],
    [0, 400, "#64FE2E"],
    [0, 600, "#00FF00"],
    [200, 0, "#F6FF33"],
    [200, 200, "#AFFC3B"],
    [200, 400, "#00FF00"],
    [200, 600, "#64FE2E"],
    [400, 0, "#FDB500"],
    [400, 200, "#8DB723"],
    [400, 400, "#AFFC3B"],
    [400, 600, "#60FC60"],
    [600, 0, "red"],
    [600, 200, "#FDB500"],
    [600, 400, "#F6FF33"],
    [600, 600, "#C0FC3E"]
];

var width = 800,
    height = 800,
    boxWidth = 200,
    boxHeight = 200;
    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var len = rects.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    CreateRect(rects[i][0],rects[i][1],rects[i][2])
}

svgContainer.append("text")
    .attr("x", 85)
    .attr("y", 125)
    .attr("font-size", 55)
    .text("3")
    .attr("onclick", "alert('You clicked A');");
```

Comment: I think that you could add a little plain text to this code so that it is a full review of the code.  like why you would change the OP code to this. and how it makes a difference.

Answer (score -2):

I had to remove some features e.g. Zoom etc.. and now my latest code looks like this,

```
var width = 800,
    height = 800,
    boxWidth = 200,
    boxHeight = 200;

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

 CreateRect(0, 0, "#C0FC3E");
 CreateRect(0, 200, "#60FC60");
 CreateRect(0, 400, "#64FE2E");
 CreateRect(0, 600, "#00FF00");

 CreateRect(200, 0, "#F6FF33");
 CreateRect(200, 200, "#AFFC3B");
 CreateRect(200, 400, "#00FF00");
 CreateRect(200, 600, "#64FE2E");

 CreateRect(400, 0, "#FDB500");
 CreateRect(400, 200, "#8DB723");
 CreateRect(400, 400, "#AFFC3B");
 CreateRect(400, 600, "#60FC60");

 CreateRect(600, 0, "red");
 CreateRect(600, 200, "#FDB500");
 CreateRect(600, 400, "#F6FF33");
 CreateRect(600, 600, "#C0FC3E");


svgContainer.append("text")
    .attr("x", 85)
    .attr("y", 125)
    .attr("font-size", 55)
    .text("3")
    .attr("onclick", "alert('You clicked A');");


function CreateRect(x, y, boxColor)
{
    svgContainer.append("rect")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("width", boxWidth)
    .attr("height", boxHeight)
    .attr("fill", boxColor);
}
```